# Facebook limit per user, per day : 50

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook, facebook-fql

Hi I have a facebook quiz  application. When a user comes to the app then he will see questions about his/her friend. Now once user answer or clicks yes/no the app will make publish to his friend's wall.

No when I see in `application >> insight >> diagonastic`  I can see user limit

```
limit per user, per day : 50
```

Now my question is if my application has 5000 daily visitors and each user posts 10 answers to their friends' wall then my app will be deleted by facebook? Is there any way to track or limit postings?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

No, you don't need to worry about app banning, because that after the limit, every post your application makes will results in an error from Facebook ("post limit exceed", something like that). But still be careful because if you post too much, very likely users will report your application as spam, and it may get banned.

To track limit postings, you can simply write your own trackings (record to database when user request to post, for example).

Comment: Hi Hoang, thanks for answering my question. Do you have exact idea how these guys doiing track http://apps.facebook.com/twentyoneq/. This application make wall posts to friends. However I noticed that sometime I am unable to make post even with new user. How they track thier wall post when to make and when to not?

Comment: @SandyFark: Facebook has setup not only post-per-user limit, but also post-per-app-per-day limit. This limit varies for application, and FB has some heuristics to regulate it.

Comment: There's a post about it here, but somewhat not up-to-date yet: http://www.takwing.idv.hk/blog/2011/graph-api-daily-post-limit-per-user-or-application/

Comment: This post is not upto date and its just in air; no real clue... cant say it good source to learn....

Comment: @SandyFark: So you have check the diagnostic page. Actually, there seems just no good source about this.

Comment: @SandiyFark: I just notice that you publish on user's friends wall. The limit you see in Diagnostic is the limit for number of post to a user himself. Do your case like this: http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?id=85851

Comment: thanks hoang to redirct me to this post. but noting there and even you will be surprise that last post there is made by me.hehe.. anyways I am sure the only people have knowledge about this trik is the poeple who running this application..http://apps.facebook.com/twentyoneq/

Comment: @SandyFark: surprise. And you are not the author of that application?